# How to redirect js by query string in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Here is my html.

```html
<head>
    <title>My Application</title>
    <script src="app.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have two js files in folder, one is for production(`app.min.js`) and another is for development(`app.debug.js`).

What I want is to switch js file by query string. Just like:

```
http://example.com/ -> use app.min.js
http://example.com/?debug=1 -> use app.dev.js
```

I try to use the following config, but it does not work.

```
server {
  server_name self-hosted.com;

  listen 80;
  root /path/to/my/project;

  proxy_buffering off;

  location / {
    if ($query_string ~ debug=1) {
      rewrite ^/app.min.js$ /app.dev.js? permanent;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The query string is part of the initial request (for the html file), the `/app.min.js` URI is a subsequent request which will not include the query string.

Comment: @RichardSmith Do you mean I need to use another html file instead ?

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your tips. `sub_filter` is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is only present in the initial request for the HTML file. The subsequent request for the JS file is contained in the value of the `src` attribute of the `script` tag.

You could use two HTML files, each with a different value for the `src` attribute, or you could use the [`sub_filter` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) to alter the value of the `src` attribute as the HTML file is delivered.

For example:

```
root /path/to/my/project;

location = / {
    if ($arg_debug) { rewrite ^ /debug.html last; }
    index index.html;
}
location = /debug.html {
    internal;
    try_files /index.html =404;
    sub_filter '<script src="app.min.js"></script>' '<script src="app.dev.js"></script>';
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://serverfault.com/a/811981 and @Richard Smith's tips, I got the solution.

```
server {
  server_name self-hosted.com;

  listen 80;
  root /path/to/my/project;

  proxy_buffering off;

  location / {
    error_page 418 = @debug;

    if ($query_string ~ debug=1) { return 418; }

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location @debug {
    sub_filter "app.min" "app.dev";
    try_files /index.html =500;
  }
}
```